# redirect specific category pages to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying this for a while but haven't found a solution yet.

I moved to wordpress and my old site is in custom CMS. the old site now goes to archive.example.com while all the new posts will be created on http://example.com

I have created different categories for new site so that it doesn't conflict with categories from old site.

I want all the request being made to old category pages to go to archive.exampmle.com

For eg:

```
http://example.com/apple
```

should go to

```
http://archive.example.com/apple
```

Also,
all the URLs under apple category should go to the archive subdomain. For eg:

```
http://example.com/apple/1234
```

should now go to

http://archive.example.com/apple/1234

I tried this

```
RedirectMatch 301 /apple/ http://archive.example.com/apple/$1
```

but it doesen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^apple
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: ^/apple worked. ^apple did not. Please edit answer, I am marking it correct. Thanks.

Comment: I have to do this for about 10 categories. so do I have to repeat above two lines (except Rewrite Engine On), for all the categories? Or can I reduce the lines?

Comment: If there are only 10 categories than you can pass a match like `^([^\/]+)` or `^(.+?)` or there are greater than that you have to write a `^(apple|cat2|cat3)`.